# What does Solve output with # and & mean

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

I tried to solve a symbolic equation using `Solve` and in that I get expressions like `#1^5 &, 1` what does this mean?

I also found it in [one of the Mathematica examples in here as](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html)  [image]

What do these `#` and `&` mean in the solution?

Comment: Apart from the linked thread above explaining what `Root[]` is, please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616) for information on what `#` and `&` do. The executive summary is that this is the best that *Mathematica* can do to represent the roots of your sextic polynomial.

Comment: @J.M.- Once, in a dark and smoky basement "club" for out-of-work mathematicians, I saw a film starring one *sextic polynomial*. So, so naughty...